# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like this question comes up all the time in SQL Server interviews but I do not know how to answer it. Cannot find a good resource online.

In SQL Server, how do I convert 2019-01-01 or 2019-01-01 HH:MM:SS to just 2019-01?

Comment: The value of a date has no format so your question doesn't make sense. Do you mean that you have strings that need to be parsed to a date?

Comment: This is not possible and the question is either seriously flawed or has been misinterpreted. `2022-03` is not a date and could never be stored as such. You could store `20220301` and only _present_ it as a string like `2022-03` but you're never going to have YYYY-MM as a date, sorry.

Comment: ` Cannot find a good resource online` While it's certainly a valid question, kinda hard to believe searching the phrase "convert YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM", or the dbms docs, didn't return *any* relevant information. What have you tried and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: I've noticed that some people choose to store a year-month as the first day of the month in a DATE type. Something like `FORMAT(datecolumn, 'yyyy-MM')` returns a string afterall.

Comment: I will upvote this because as the OP stated, this is a SQL Server interview question and in my opinion, it is a trick question. They are trying to gage your logical competence. They want you to think through the solution and answer accordingly. No way to convert to invalid date format, only display as varchar.

Answer (score 3):

> In MS SQL, how do I convert 2019-01-01 or 2019-01-01 HH:MM: SS to just 2019-01 **while keeping it as a date data type**? *[emphasis added]*

You can't. SQL Server's [`date` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) represents a specific calendar day, not a month. 2019-01 is not a day.

(You can, of course, output only the year and month component when converting the `date` to one of SQL Server's string data types.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question. There is no date format without values for all three (day, month, and year). This fails:

```
CREATE TABLE #fake_date (fake_date DATETIME)
INSERT #fake_date
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM')

SELECT * FROM #fake_date
DROP TABLE #fake_date
```

However, you can display year-month as a varchar by simply using the FORMAT function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

As many already mentioned, SQL Server doesn't have a built-in data type for a 'YYYY-MM'.

Though SQL Server's XML/XQuery/XSD does have it: `xs:gYearMonth`

For the reference: [Constructor Functions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/constructor-functions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, dateColumn DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl (dateColumn) VALUES
('2019-01-01'),
('2019-12-31'),
(NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, dateColumn
    , result = c.query('/r/text()').value('xs:gYearMonth(substring(.,1,7))', 'CHAR(7)')
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<r>' + CAST(dateColumn AS CHAR(10)) + '</r>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+---------+
| ID | dateColumn | result  |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01 |
|  2 | 2019-12-31 | 2019-12 |
|  3 | NULL       | NULL    |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Neither the input *nor* the output is XML, so I can't fathom why you'd use that here. `xs:gYearMonth` does nothing here, since the `substring` is doing the actual work. It's both more complicated and less efficient than just manipulating a string representation directly. `gYearMonth` has *some* use in typed XML that adheres to a schema, but that requires quite a bit more setup and is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT CONCAT(year(datefield), '-', month(datefield)) FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.